# Understand the definition of a neighborhood of a point in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

I'm a physics grad student and recently I decided that I would properly learn differential geometry. I then decided that I would start to learn what a topological space is then build up from there since I was told that a proper understanding of general topology is pivotal to proper learn differential geometry. The thing is, right at the beginning of my endeavor I stumbled on the definition of [neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)). My doubt is:a neighborhood of a point $x$ in some topological space $X$ - I know I should put a pair with the set and the topology but bear with me - is a subset of $X$ that contains an open set that contains $x$. The definition of [open set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) is that it's a member of the topology of the topological space.

Now from the definition of neighborhood of a point how can I prove the example given at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) where it is stated that a rectangle isn't a neighborhood of any of its corners.

Comment: Because the open set which contains the corner will never be a subset of the rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the example is in the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$; equivalently, you can consider the definition of neighborhood given in the caption of the first picture. If you consider any open set $U$ that contains a corner $x$, it will contain some points outside of the rectangle so $U$ cannot be contained in the rectangle.

Comment: Ah so the space isn't the rectangle but some other subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @PML Yes. To see this, note that the question you asked concerns whether a rectangle is or isn't a neighborhood of its corners. From the definition of neighborhood that you gave, it is a subset of $X$.

Comment: I don't follow. I got it why a rectangle isn't a neighborhood of its corners if I consider that the rectangle is contained in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ - since the rectangle is contained in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is an open subset that contains $x$ that isn't contained in the rectangle - but what if the rectangle is the whole space, isn't it a neighborhood of its corners? Maybe I misread your comment but you seem to imply that it isn't.

Comment: @PML Sorry for being unclear. I was not giving reasoning for the proof, but reasoning why I think the writer of the Wikipedia caption implicitly states that the rectangle is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and that the topology is on $\mathbb{R}^2$. In general, you are correct that if the rectangle is the whole space, then it is a neighborhood of any of its points.